# Download system-polyfills.js through npm

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, polyfills

I want to download some polyfills for the Microsoft internet explorer browser:

```
<script src="node_modules/es6-shim/es6-shim.min.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system-polyfills.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/angular2/es6/dev/src/testing/shims_for_IE.js"></script>
```

I have succeeded to download `es6-shim.min.js` and `shims_for_IE.js` through the next commands:

```
npm install es6-shim
npm install angular2
```

but I wasn't able to download `system-polyfills.js` in the same way.
How can I find this file?

Thanks in advance

Kobi

Answer (score 2):

Try installing an older version of **systemjs** for example you will find the system-polyfills.js in the  dist folder of the 0.19.24 systemjs package you can install it using this command:

```
npm install systemjs@'0.19.24'
```